# Custom Role Provider

Tags: asp.net, role, roleprovider

I'm in charge of supporting an intranet website that has different applications. Each application has it's own security with it's own set of groups and users with specific authorizations.

I'm just trying to figure out how to use Identity (role, users and memberships) so that it would be easier to manage users and groups. Also, the intranet website would have one standard way for all the security.

I'm kind of a new with Identity and I don't want to upgrade to MVC. We are using webforms with C# code behind.

All users would have to create their account. Then I would have different roles (groups of users) for all applications. That would be good. Then, a couple of authorization to folders in the web.config based on the roles. But how to know which role is assigned to which application? Custom property or attribute to role?
Is it possible to extend the base class role provider?

I forgot to mention that we are using code first.

Thank you.

Comment: But how to know which role is assigned to which application?  - more applications are using the same web.config?

Comment: The way it is setup right now is one big web.config for the portal.  And, every application (in their respective folders) has it's own little web.config.

Comment: see my answer + you can include the group names in the own web configs in the folders.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  Do you think it would be simpler with MVC or do you think there is something else out of the box that would be more appropriate?

Comment: It can be a little bit simpler but dont expect a significant difference here.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer is to add to the group names an application specific part and use this to find the appropriate role(s).